# Matlab doesn't read files with tilde (~) instead of full home path

Tags: matlab, unix, file-io

I've noticed a strange behavior of Matlab when accessing files. Say I have a path to a file like this:

```
path = '~/data/file'
```

If I run `exist(path)`, the result is `2`, i.e. the file exists. If I run

```
textread(path, '%s')
```

then I get an error message

```
Error using dataread
File not found or permission denied.
```

However, if I expand the tilde and run `textread`, it works fine:

```
path2 = '/home/username/data/file'
textread(path2, '%s')
```

Can you explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `exist` understands relative paths (as identified by the tilde), whereas `textread` does not.

Note that [textscan](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) is now the preferred way of reading data from a file - this accepts file identifiers so will work with relative paths.

If this is not an option, a good GetFullPath function can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28249-getfullpath).

Comment: Is there a way to automatically expand the relative path so that `textread` can access it?

Comment: Alright, looking in the documentation, I've found: "`textread` is not recommended. Use `textscan` instead." And `textscan` uses file identifiers.

Comment: A useful `GetFullPath` function has been written - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28249-getfullpath, for information on usage have a look at http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/04/01/be-absolute-about-your-relative-path-with-getfullpath/

Comment: Or you could use textscan instead (probably preferable) - I'll add this to my answer